# Adding extra column name and row name to a table in R?

Tags: r, formatting, xtable

I have a table which I generated from `table()` function and I further use xtable to print it as follows:

```
          FF NF NN Sum
     FF   8  0  0   8
     NF   7  8  0  15
     NN   3  1  4   8
```

I want to add an additional column name and a rowname in the following format.

```
           Time2
   Time1 FF NF NN Sum
     FF   8  0  0   8
     NF   7  8  0  15
     NN   3  1  4   8
```

I looked into xtable but couldn't find anything. colnames() changes the names of the existing columns, rownames() does the same to the rownames.

Comment: `data.frame(table())`

Comment: @Ananta,thanks ! I tried doing this but it won't help as there is a column/rown name already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a couple of options.

The first is to add those names to the table object "by hand".

```
## An example of a table object with unnamed dimnames 
x <- with(warpbreaks, table(unname(wool), unname(tension)))
x
#     L M H
#   A 9 9 9
#   B 9 9 9

names(dimnames(x)) <- c("Time1", "Time2")
x
#      Time2
# Time1 L M H
#     A 9 9 9
#     B 9 9 9
```

The second (and typically preferable) option is to supply the names in your initial call to `table()`, like this:

```
table(Time1 = warpbreaks[[2]], Time2 = warpbreaks[[3]])
#      Time2
# Time1 L M H
#     A 9 9 9
#     B 9 9 9
```

Comment: thanks. dimnames() for a table makes sense.i wasted so much time focusing on colnames().

Comment: @Arihant -- Yeah, I recall being similarly stumped by this at one point. Doing `str(x)` (especially on a table object `x` that *does* display the names of the dimensions) *might* have given you the clue you needed.